# Is there any way to fix my iMac which can't boot?

Tags: imac, startup

I have an iMac 27' bought in about 2014 (can't see the detail model because I can't turn it on).

Due to covid-19, I left my iMac at my friend's house for over 6 months.

The iMac was never booted during this period and today I suddenly found it's not able to boot.

When I pressed the power button, nothing happens, the screen remains black.

I guess maybe it's because I have left the iMac unpowered for months.

Is there anything I could do to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've ruled out silly things (e.g., by first plugging your power cord into another device and confirming that it's working so you know that your cord + power outlet are good), it is next to certain that your **RTC battery** (which backs the SMC [which drives power sequencing] in the absence of main power) needs replacement.

Unfortunately, although the coin cell itself is a standard CR2032, it's not at all easy to get to, as you have to separate the display from the chassis. You can pay an Apple authorized service center to do this for a nominal fee, or you can attempt to do it yourself by investing in a "pizza cutter" tool and being EXTREMELY careful not to touch the power supply board (which has large capacitors that were recently charged [because you tried powering the system on] and **WILL kill you**). There are many guides and videos available online that will walk you through this if you want to try it yourself.